# how can add store to magento in cpanel share host

Tags: magento-1.9.1.1

i am using cpanel sharing host and can't access ssh 

before i create this question i searched in google and this site and stackoverflow about add second store to magento store
most of site write similar thing , use symlink for virtual server and use htaccess modification for host. 

i test all of theme but get 404 error. i am tired of search . maybe you do this in shared host such as cpanel or direct admin then can you help me to add second store to my magento store ?

my store base url is : **shop.com**

i want to add second store with this name : **shop.com/store2**

and later add other store to this shop

i read all of this toturial and don't get answer . **my magento is 1.9.1**

1-http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

2-https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains

3-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091175/how-to-add-create-new-store-in-magento-1-7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

very thanks from my friends for answer to me

i found answer very easily than i think!

 **MagenX** was say right but don't say 1 thing ! , and it is that add code to your store in configuration -> web must be on Yes , i defined that but don't get True Answer but with this do i am be Successful for add store and activate it on my main website.

 Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are tying to have 2 stores on the single domain. If this assumption is right, you are not going to need to have anything done at the server setup level, except a properly working Apache!

Since you are creating 2 stores, I'll take the liberty to assume that you already have the root category for second store (you can share the existing root category between stores as well) and created the 2nd store from admin as well.

Now, you'll need to set the base URLs for your second store from `System -> Configuration -> General -> Web`. Be careful to set those URLs at the store level only. You'll also need to modify the entries below that for original location of JS/CSS/Media files.

Now, create a folder like "store2" on the magento installation root, and copy the .htaccess and index.php files from original Magento installation.
Then edit .htaccess file and locate `RewriteBase` in there, put the path to your folder after that and un-comment that line.

In your index.php file, locate `define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());` and convert it to `define('MAGENTO_ROOT', '..');`

This is all what is needed to have the second store. In some cases, you may need to add `MAGE_RUN_CODE` environment variable also in your .htaccess file, it's value will be your store code.

Having a new store requires Magento indexes to be re-built, so don't forget to do that afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is just to configure your second store by selecting store view in dropdown menu on the left top side in magento admin. there you will be able to setup all paths and even theme package name. then you add to your .htaccess file your store code for this specific path.
and thats it.
no need to create anything else, no mess with extra folders and index.php

but i highly recommend to use subdomains, just point it from cpanel to the same webroot as your main store add store code to .htaccess and thats it.

the most important is base url in configuration => web

Comment: thanks for your answer but 1 important thing is forget! i completed your answer.thanks Again